# Grafana filter jobs and targets

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I need to filter a table based on

1. job
   and then
2. instance

In prometheus.yml I have "node_exporter" job with targets (port:9100)
and "telegraf" job with targets (port:9273)
In grafana dashboard I have a variable for each job showing the proper targets,

How do I query the table to present the relevant data from each variable?
I was thinking on merging "up" and "node_uname_info" metrics..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- PromQL of the display

First, you need to know the PromQL of the display information obtained from Prometheus
e.g you have metrics like this

> probe_success{env="xxx",instance="http://xxxx.com",job="xxxx-job"} 1

so, you can query by

> probe_success{env="var1",instance="var1",job="var1"}

- Declare the variables you need in grafana.
  [image]

[image: variable job setting]

[image: The variable target is a combination of more variables to query]

- Queries setting

Temporarily store your variables with PromQL in 'Queries' , like 'A'
[image: A]

- TABLE

Set Visualization = 'TABLE' and use Value to display

[image: column setting]

Last , i think you can get more dashboard on grafana https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/
try to copy the dashboard, and on these basis, modify it to meet your own requirements.

Comment: Cheers thank a lot mate!!